# Kotlinx synthetic and AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin-extension, androidx

After migrating to AndroidX I found that in *some*, not all of my classes the `kotlinx.android.synthetic` fields are now failing to convert to the actual class.

> Widget has an unresolved type 'androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout', and
>   thus it was upcasted to 'android.view.View'

Is `kotlinx.android.synthetic` currently incompatible with AndroidX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using `androidx` with `kotlinx.android.synthetic` and a drawer layout with no issues. I believe the drawer layout tag should be `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`.

Comment: Yup, just realized that's the delta.  Some of the layout files migrated in the studio conversion.  Some didn't.  `Migrate to AndroidX` arguably shouldn't have been released in it's current state.  I ended up going file by file anyway and it only created an illusion that it helped.

Comment: To make it worse, in my case, the `DrawerLayout` was actually converted in the layout, but random other ones were not, causing the layout to ostensibly look converted at the top.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into basically the same thing when I updated an app last week.